# Testing with EmbeddedKafka - Test report

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-kafka, jacoco-maven-plugin, embedded-kafka

I'm using `EmbeddedKafka` to test the integration with Kafka in my microservice. And also, I'm using jacoco for publishing the test result. Inorder to make the test run without any issue, I have to make the `forkCount` parameter as `0`.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*ITest.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>               
        </plugin>
```

If not, it fails with error the following error:

> MojoFailureException: Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log

The problem is since I'm making the forkCount as `0`, the jacoco plugin fails to generate report, as it couldn't start as `javaagent`. Is there workaround for this?

Comment: well it does not work for me at all even with forkCount 0. I have no idea why the fork cannot be started.